# What Happened to Mestral?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise, vulcan

In Star Trek: Enterprise episode Carbon Creek (Season 2 Episode 02):

> Mestral decides to stay on Earth. Even though T'Pol suggests it's just a story, the end of the episode reveals it may be based in fact.

I'm curious if there is any more in-universe explanation about what may have happened as a result of this story.

I haven't read any Star Trek-related literature, so I'm also curious whether anyone has written any books or short stories addressing this.

Answer (score 4):

The character of Mestral is a key player in the Trek novel [From History's Shadow](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/From_History's_Shadow). Mestral is brought forward 300 years into the future where he reveals that he has been living on Earth since the 1960's and has been instrumental in a number of key scientific and cultural events. The very clear implication is that his continued presence on Earth is vital to the ultimate foundation of the Federation:

> “I am grateful to you for allowing me to return to Earth, Miss
>   Lincoln.” He nodded to Kirk. “And to you, Captain.”. “Earth?” McCoy
>   asked, frowning. “Not Vulcan?”
>
> Mestral replied, “It is my desire to continue my observations of Earth
>   and humanity, Doctor. The time period I left was something of a
>   turning point in your history, and I wish to be on hand to see what
>   happens next.”
>
> “What if you’re discovered?” McCoy asked. “Won’t that affect our
>   history, too?” Lincoln said, “We’ll be keeping tabs on Mister Mestral
>   as well, Doctor. Besides, how do you know his being on Earth doesn’t
>   prove beneficial to our history in some way?” She said nothing else,
>   leaving the cryptic question to hang in the air as she retrieved her
>   servo from a pocket. She keyed the device, and a blue-black fog
>   appeared at the rear of the transporter chamber.

---

There's also short story titled "[Mestral](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Mestral_(short_story))" (by Ben Guilfoy) in the fan-fiction anthology [Strange New Worlds IX](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Strange_New_Worlds_9).

The story tells of Vulcan explorer Mestral interacting with a crazy young scientist named Zefram Cochrane, helping him navigate a world where Eastern Coalition troops are invading the United States. In addition to inspiring him to continue with his research, he also introduces his new friend "zee" to a young aeronautical engineer called Lily Sloane.

At the end of the story...

> we see Mestral wandering off into the woods with an apparent gunshot wound to the abdomen. In the absence of medical assistance, his chances of survival seem slim.

Comment: A little known fact is that Mestral was instrumental in the beginnings of Heavy Metal throughout the late 60s to early 70s. In fact, he was quite possibly "the man in the back" mentioned in Sweet's 'Ballroom Blitz'.

Comment: @Omegacron - I heard that he was the 5th Beatle : http://i.stack.imgur.com/yDT2B.jpg

Comment: well, the haircut fits :P

Answer (score -3):

It is likely he contacted the NASA director of space flight Van Braun, and became his chief assistant (under an assumed identity) thus greatly assisting in the Saturn V sub orbit booster rocket development program.  He probably gained Von Braun's trust and told him the truth of his Vulcan identity, which Werner would have willingly kept this secret to the grave. (towards the end of his life he more than likely would have mentioned the Vulcan in his late 80's- but everyone would have just thought the crazy old rocket scientist was dreaming of Martins in senile state of mind)  Mestral would have continued his work with science, eventually helping Cochrane towards the end of his life.  Also it is very likely he had plastic surgery in the 80's or 90's to make his ears and eye brows look human, claiming it was a birth defect knowing he would never return to Vulcan.  This also raises the question if he had any children, during his 300 year stay on earth?

Comment: This looks like a lot of speculation.

Comment: This is raw speculation.

Comment: This appears to be a work of fan-fiction rather than an answer to the question.